# SHAP with PySpark MLLib models

Tags: python, pyspark, shap

I have trained a series of models on Databricks using PySpark Pipelines via MLLib. I want to create SHAP explanations for my output to understand why certain observations are being scored in different ways. However, all my attempts at getting the Python `shap` package to work with these models have failed. Here's what I've tried.

Suppose I've already trained a pipeline model (mod) on my PySpark dataframes (train and test):

```
import shap

train_schema = train.schema
train_df = train.toPandas()
test_df = test.toPandas()
```

I was using `shap.KernelExplainer` because it accepts a function as input instead of a model and shap does not accept either MLLib models or PySpark dataframes as input. The function converts the data back to spark, does a prediction, then transforms it back to pandas format.

```
def model_func(df):
  spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=train_schema)
  return mod.transform(spark_df).select('prediction').toPandas().values.reshape(-1)

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model_func, train_df.iloc[:50,:], link="identity", keep_index=True)
```

It works up to here. But if I try to create shap values, it throws an attribute error:

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_df.iloc[0,:])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-749e214aaaab> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 shap_values = explainer(test_df.iloc[0,:])

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/shap/explainers/_explainer.py in __call__(self, max_evals, main_effects, error_bounds, batch_size, outputs, silent, *args, **kwargs)
    213         start_time = time.time()
    214 
--> 215         if issubclass(type(self.masker), maskers.OutputComposite) and len(args)==2:
    216             self.masker.model = models.TextGeneration(target_sentences=args[1])
    217             args = args[:1]

AttributeError: 'Kernel' object has no attribute 'masker'
```

I've tried including a masker in the KernelExplainer but I'm really just not sure what the error means.

Is there a way to generate shap explanations on PySpark models?

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you want to use shap.explainers or explainers from interpret.ext.blackbox.

If you prefer to use shap.KernelExplainer, you can wrap `mod.transform(spark_df).select('prediction').toPandas()` inside a class. You just need to make sure the class has a predict method and whatever you pass in the KernelExplainers is compatible (i.e pandas dataframe).

```
class wrapper:
  def __init__(self,columns,model):
    self.cols = cols 
    self.model = model

  def predict(self,args):
     # turning the pandas dataframe back to a pyspark dataframe
     spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(args,self.cols)
     prediction_results = self.model.transform(spark_df)
     output = predictions.select("predictions").toPandas().values.flatten()
     return output 
  
custom_model = wrapper(columns_list,pyspark_model)

# Make sure train_df is a pandas dataframe 
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(custom_model.predict,
                                 train_df.toPandas())

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_df)
global_importance = np.abs(shap_values).mean(0)
```

You can technically do the same if you wish to use explainers from interpret.ml.blackbox. You can also reference their API [documentations](https://github.com/interpretml/interpret-community)

[image: Compatibility]

There are two ways of doing it - I will simply show the easier way.

```
# Assuming you have used mlflow to log an experiment and register the model 
loaded_model =  mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("model_path_goes_here")

class wrapper():
  def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model
    
  def predict(self, X):
    predictions = self.model.predict(X)
    return np.array([[1-p, p] for p in predictions])

wrapper = wrapper(loaded_model)
explainer = KernelExplainer(
              wrapper,
              initialization_examples = train_df,
              features = train_df.columns.tolist(),
              classes=[0, 1],
              model_task='classification')

explainer.explain_global(train_df.sample(frac=0.002))
explainer.explain_local(test_df)
```

I am also training models on Databricks using Pyspark pipelines. Although I got these explainers to work, I have yet to figure out a way to pickle these explainers. Regardless, I think you should try making custom model wrappers and see if it works for you as well.